Internal consent screen shows user is blocked for calling YT insert video API
We have a GCP project opened by with a gSuite account.
We've created an internal consent screen.
How come when we try to approve the consent screen (while using a corp email before calling the YT insert API) -we get 403 error + "user is blocked"?
Worth mentioning:

We use individual OAuth tokens for each channel
Login works when choosing a managed youtube channel account.
Channels are owned by gsuite corp workspace account as well as all channels managers.

Can it be that domain channels were created outside of their gSuite net, despite the owner is a gSuite account (thought so since there were no options to change any "domain channel")?

